# How to use javascript to turn off HTML5 audio when checkbox is unchecked?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, html5-audio

I have the following javascript code to play some HTML5 sounds:

```
    var html5_audiotypes={ //define list of audio file extensions and their associated audio types. Add to it if your specified audio file isn't on this list:
        "mp3": "audio/mpeg",
        "mp4": "audio/mp4",
        "ogg": "audio/ogg",
        "wav": "audio/wav"
    }

    function createsound(sound){
        var html5audio=document.createElement('audio')
        if (html5audio.canPlayType){ //check support for HTML5 audio
            for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
                var sourceel=document.createElement('source')
                sourceel.setAttribute('src', arguments[i])
                if (arguments[i].match(/\.(\w+)$/i))
                    sourceel.setAttribute('type', html5_audiotypes[RegExp.$1])
                html5audio.appendChild(sourceel)
            }
            html5audio.load()
            html5audio.playclip=function(){
                html5audio.pause()
                html5audio.currentTime=0
                html5audio.play()
            }
            return html5audio
        }
        else{
            return {playclip:function(){throw new Error("Your browser doesn't support HTML5 audio")}}
        }
    }

//Initialize two sound clips with 1 fallback file each:
var sound1=createsound("audio/tileSelect.ogg", "audio/tileSelect.mp3")
var sound2=createsound("audio/tileRemove.ogg", "audio/tileRemove.mp3")
```

With `sound1.playclip();` used in other functions I can play the sounds

The problem:

I have a checkbox with ID: `sound`. When checked, the sound should be heard, if not, no sound should be heard.

The code for the checkbox currently is:

```
function playSound() {
    if (document.getElementById('sound').checked){
        [something has to be added here?]
    }
}
```

What do I need to add in this part to hear the sound when checked and not when unchecked? I can't seem to get it working.

Kind regards,
Maurice

Comment: You need to attach a click listener to the checkbox

Comment: The checkbox status is saved in a cookie so when returning to the site, the status is "remembered" hence the click function is not used (in this case). So it should mute sound on the condition of the checkbox as I've tried with my incomplete if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I solved it. I was thinking too hard, it can be done very simple:

```
if (document.getElementById('sound').checked){
                sound1.playclip(); 
            }
```

This works